# Stub internal calls on dependency of library with Sinon.js

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

I am writing a library which has an entry file that looks like this:

```
function MyLibrary(options){

   this._options = {// defaults here};

   this.setupOptions(options);
   this._initInstance();
}

MyLibrary.prototype.randomMethod = function(){

}

MyLibrary.prototype._initInstance = function(){
   this._loadImage();
   this._internalInstance = new OtherThirdPartyDependency(this._options);
}

module.exports = MyLibrary;
```

In my tests, I would like to create a real instance of `MyLibrary`, but I want to create a stub of `OtherThirdPartyDependency`.

Here is my test file so far. How can I achieve this?

```
describe('My Library Module', () => {

    let sandbox;
    let myLibInstance;

    beforeEach(() => {
        sandbox = sinon.createSandbox({});
        myLibInstance = new MyLibrary({option: 1, option: 2}); 
        // FAILS HERE because initializing MyLibrary make a call OtherThirdPartyDependency constructor. 
    });

    afterEach(() => {
        sandbox.restore();
    });

    it('should call setOptions and _loadImage on init', () => {

        expect(myLibInstance.setOptions).to.have.been.calledOnce;
        expect(myLibInstance._loadImage).to.have.been.calledOnce;
    })

});
```

There is a method in [sinon](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v7.3.2/stubs/) `createStubInstance`, but I'm not sure how to apply in here because `OtherThirdPartyDependency` is not a method that I can directly stub on `MyLibrary`. How can I stub `OtherThirdPartyDependency`?